# Potential risk of multiple threads sharing the same handle in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am wondering if there is any potential risk when multiple threads share the same handle using pthread in linux? I just tried the following simple code: create two threads using `pthread_create` and assign them the same `pthread_t` handle, and then let them run. The output seems that both threads are running normally, although I think this is definitely not the right way to do it, so what potential risk could it have? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *thread_1(void *arg){
    while(1){
        sleep(1);
        printf("threading 1...\n");
    }
}

static void *thread_2(void *arg){
    while(1){
        sleep(2);
        printf("threading 2...\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t handler;
    pthread_create(&handler, NULL, thread_1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&handler, NULL, thread_2, NULL);

    (void) pthread_join(handler, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried compiled and run the test code, and there seems no visible error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your concern is that `pthread_t` is an opaque type that might actually store valuable information about the thread, and so you cannot use the same one for two threads.

On Linux (which you tagged), it is just an `unsigned long`:

```
typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;
```

Therefore, I don't think there is anything "stored" in the type, other than its ID. So what you are doing is safe, other than you lose the ID of the first thread.

You do not have two threads sharing one handle. You have a single variable that stores the ID of the second thread. The first thread has a different ID which you threw away.

Comment: Thanks you! From your and @TruthSeeker's answers, can I say: "Thread 1 is running correctly, but `main()` is unable to monitor it, since the only ID it has is occupied by thread 2, and will return once thread 2 terminates, even if thread 1 is still alive"?

Comment: Yes, the `join()` will only return when thread 2 finishes. There is no way to monitor thread 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `handler` is overwritten by second `pthread_create` function call. Hence `main` is waiting for termination of the second thread.

As both `thread_1` and `thread_2` are infinite loop code will not reach `pthread_join` function call and hence no visible change.

If you remove the infinite loop in second thread you would notice the termination of the process.